# Borrow mutable in a loop

Tags: multithreading, rust, parallel-processing, borrow-checker, crossbeam

I try to process an array with multiple worker threads, just like Rayon's `par_iter()` function, but i want to have a mutable reference `target`, one for each thread.

I have a simple function like this

```
pub fn parallel_map_vector<A:Sync,T:Send,B:Send>(a:&[A], t:&mut [T], b:&mut [B], f:impl Fn(&A,&mut T)+Send+Sync){
    assert_eq!(a.len(),b.len());
    let atomic_counter = AtomicUsize::new(0);
    crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
        for target in t {
            scope.spawn( |_| {
                loop {
                    let idx = atomic_counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
                    if idx < a.len() {unsafe{std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(b,b_len)};
                        f(&a[idx], target)
                    }else{
                        break
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).unwrap();
}
```

For some reason i keep getting the error

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `target`, which is owned by the current function
  --> htm/src/parallel.rs:11:26
   |
9  |     crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
   |                       ----- has type `&crossbeam::thread::Scope<'1>`
10 |         for target in t {
11 |             scope.spawn( |_| {
   |                          ^^^ may outlive borrowed value `target`
...
17 |                         f(&a[idx], target)
   |                                    ------ `target` is borrowed here
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'1`
  --> htm/src/parallel.rs:11:13
   |
11 | /             scope.spawn( |_| {
12 | |                 loop {
13 | |                     let idx = atomic_counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
14 | |                     if idx < a.len() {
...  |
21 | |                 }
22 | |             });
   | |______________^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `target` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
11 |             scope.spawn( move |_| {
```

but when i try it in rust playground it compiles without problem
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0a10cbfd2f135975f4682c843664d539
What could be wrong here? The code looks safe to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The playground example to which you have linked is using the 2021 edition of Rust, which allows [disjoint capture in closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/disjoint-capture-in-closures.html) (and hence the closure for each thread captures only `target` rather than the entire `t` slice).  If you [switch to the 2018 edition](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0a10cbfd2f135975f4682c843664d539), it yields the same error as in your question.

Specify that you require the 2021 edition in your `Cargo.toml` (requires rustc >= 1.56.0).